# How to configure Apache forward to IIS

Tags: apache, iis, varnish

My website running on IIS 8.0.

I was install **Ubuntu** on another machine, and setup **Apache and Varnish** on it.

Now, I want **how to configure Varnish and Apache when visitors access Apache that it will forward  to my Website on IIS**.

Please help me!!!

Answer (score 0):

As your question, you need varnish and apache to send the visitor to IIS Server .

I could not understand why you need apache to send To IIS which will cause your page load slower due to unnecessary routing.

But to answer your query 
in apache config:

```
sudo vi /etc/apache2/apache2.conf
```

add below

```
ProxyPass "/" "http://IISserverip/"
ProxyPassReverse "/" "http://IISserverip/"
```

hope this resolve your requirement